# How to prove $n^6$ is big-O but not big-Omega of the function $(1.001)^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

I know that, $n^c \in \mathcal{O}(2^n)$ for any constant $c$. 
However, I don't know how to prove, or whether it is correct that, $n^c \in \mathcal{O}(1.001)^n$ for any constant $c$. Does anyone has an idea?

What I have tried so far:

By definition, $n^6 \in \mathcal{O}(1.001)^n \iff n^6 \leq c \cdot 1.001^n$ for $n \geq n_0$, where $n_0$ is a non-negative integer and $c$ is a positive integer.

How do I go from here?

Comment: Try taking logarithms.

Comment: Is it that $\log_{1.001}n^6 \in \mathcal{O}(n)$?

Comment: Don’t worry about the base of the logarithm. It only matters up to a constant. Then consider properties of logarithms

Comment: Ah, it goes nearly flat as $n$ goes to infinity. Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The proofs for $n^c \in \mathcal O(2^n)$ and $n^c \in \mathcal O((1.001)^n)$ are basically the same. You can prove:

**Proposition**. For arbitrary constants $c > 0$ and $r > 1$, we have $n^c \in \mathcal O(r^n)$.

*Proof*.
First, note that
$$\begin{align*}
n^c \le Cr^n
&\iff \log n^c \le \log Cr^n\\
&\iff c\log n - n\log r \le \log C.
\end{align*}$$
Thus it suffices to prove that a function
$$ f(x) = c\log x - x\log r \quad (x > 0)$$
is bounded from above. As 
$$f'(x) = \frac{c}{x} - \log r \begin{cases}
> 0 \quad \left(x < \tfrac{c}{\log r}\right)\\
= 0 \quad \left(x = \tfrac{c}{\log r}\right)\\
< 0 \quad \left(x > \tfrac{c}{\log r}\right),
\end{cases}$$
the function $f$ has a maximum $f\left(\tfrac{c}{\log r}\right) = c\log \tfrac{c}{\log r} - c = \log \left(\tfrac{c}{e\log r}\right)^c$.

Hence we get $n^c \le \left(\tfrac{c}{e\log r}\right)^cr^n$ for $n \ge 1$; in particular, $n^c \in \mathcal O(r^n)$.

Answer (score 0):

For any positive $n$:

\begin{align*}
1.001^n&=e^{n \ln 1.001}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n\ln 1.001)^k}{k!}\\
&>\frac{(n \ln 1.001)^7}{7!}&\text{(because all the terms in the sum are positive)}\\
&=\frac{(\ln 1.001)^7}{7!}n^7 \, .
\end{align*}